# Converting Mon Sep 09 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) with c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Do anyone have an idea how to convert `Mon Sep 09 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` date into C# DateTime object.
I tried `DateTime.Parse()` and `DateTime.TryParseExact()` but no luck.

Comment: You tried *what* **exactly**? Show the **exact** code you have tried and **how** it didn't work (include errors perhaps and don't be skimpy on the details, include the whole stack trace).

Comment: I am passing the date in context as a string.

Comment: @Arran: I realized my format was incorrect.

Comment: @IrfanRaza: post your code! You are using the correct method but you're obviously not using it *correctly* - your question shows no evidence of your effort.

Comment: That's great @IrfanRaza , but next time, post the exact code you are using. Once you had done that, you would have probably noticed your mistake and just deleted your question in the first place!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to create `DateTime` object from any string format.

```
var stringDate = "Mon Sep 09 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
        stringDate,
        "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```